# Hotkey to play selected folder/s on windows explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, autohotkey, vbscript, aimp

If one or more folders on windows explorer are selected and then "Alt + Intro" is pressed, windows shows the properties of those folders. I would like to make a custom hotkey to play the files in the folder/s on AIMP. I can see the "Play" option on the right click menu of the folders. Is it possible to make a script which does that?

Comment: Does your keyboard have a context menu key? If yes you can press that and then the key that is underlined for whatever you wanna do with the files. For example `menu key + enter` if "Play" is the first option in your context menu, or `menu key + P` if "Play" has an underlined "P".

Comment: yes, it does, and thank you for the answer. That's what I do now, it's fast, but I was trying to get that to the next level.